# NSDictionary with string constants and ids

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, constants

I'm looking for nice solution for the problem.
I need about 20+ string constants (resources filenames). But I'll need to:

1. Group constants (filenames)
2. Iterate through selected group of constants
3. Access constants by their id

So the best solution I found was to create constant NSDictionary for each group with constant values and ids. 
I wanted to use `enum` for storing constants ids but int couldn't be used as key in NSDictionary.

```obj-c
typedef enum {
    kSoundColorSelection1 = 0,
    kSoundColorSelection2,
    kSoundColorSelection3,
    kSoundFill1,
    kSoundFill2,
    kSoundSizeSelectionBig,
    kSoundSizeSelectionMedium
} ACSoundId;
```

"Easiest" way is explicitly convert `int` to `NSNumber`

```obj-c
templatesSounds = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"album_close.caf",[NSNumber numberWithInt:kSoundAlbumClose],
                 @"album_open.caf", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kSoundAlbumOpen], nil];
```

is there any other way to keep constants in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use an NSNumber as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: Since you would like to use integer values as keys I would recommend explicitly setting all of the values in the enum.

Comment: Why dont you load them from a nib?

Comment: Because I don't have nibs in my app

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to make this easier.

**Solution 1**
If you are using the ACSoundId as the key to your NSDictionary, you could just use an NSArray:

```
typedef enum {
    kSoundColorSelection1      = 0,
    kSoundColorSelection2      = 1,
    kSoundColorSelection3      = 2,
    kSoundFill1                = 3,
    kSoundFill2                = 4,
    kSoundSizeSelectionBig     = 5,
    kSoundSizeSelectionMedium  = 6
} ACSoundId;
```

Store sounds in an Array in the same order they are defined in the above enum:

```
templatesSounds = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"color_selection1.caf",
    @"color_selection2.caf",
    @"color_selection3.caf",
    @"color_fill1.caf",
    @"color_fill2.caf",
    @"size_selection_big.caf",
    @"size_selection_medium.caf",
    nil];
```

Since the index of the sounds would correlate to the values of the enum, it would work similar to a NSDirectory:

```
queuedSound = [templatesSounds objectAtIndex:kSoundColorSelection2];
```

**Solution 2**
Alternatively you could create a category to make it easier to use integers as keys in an NSDictionary:

Define the category:

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (NSNumberDictionary)
- (void) setObject:(id)anObject forNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber;
- (void) removeObjectForNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber;
- (id)   objectForNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber;
@end
```

Implement the category:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (NSNumberDictionary)
- (void) setObject:(id)anObject forNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber
{
   NSNumber * number;
   number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:aNumber];
   [self setObject:anObject forKey:number];
   [number release];
   return;
}
- (void) removeObjectForNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber
{
   NSNumber * number;
   number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:aNumber];
   [self removeObjectForKey:number];
   [number release];
   return;
}
- (id) objectForNumber:(NSInteger)aNumber
{
   NSNumber * number;
   id         object;
   number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:aNumber];
   object = [self objectForKey:number];
   [number release];
   return(object);
}
@end
```

Use the category:

```
templatesSounds = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithWithCapacity1];
[templatesSounds setObject:@"color_selection1.caf" forNumber:kSoundColorSelection1];
[templatesSounds setObject:@"color_selection2.caf" forNumber:kSoundColorSelection2];
[templatesSounds setObject:@"color_selection3.caf" forNumber:kSoundColorSelection3];
[templatesSounds setObject:@"color_fill1.caf"      forNumber:kSoundColorFill1];
[templatesSounds setObject:@"color_fill2.caf"      forNumber:kSoundColorFill2];
```

Comment: As I told I have few groups. One solution - have enum per group, but it will generate warning, as I use ACSoundId as type for an argument.

Comment: @OgreSwamp What do you mean an enum per group?  Can you expand upon your code so we can have a more clear picture of how the enums are used?

Answer (score 1):

If your "keys" are integers always, why not use normal C arrays?

```
NSString **templatesSounds ;

int numConstants = 10;
templatesSounds = calloc(numConstants , sizeof(NSString*));

templatesSounds[kSoundAlbumOpen] = @"album_open.caf";

NSString* soundName = templatesSounds [kSoundSizeSelectionMedium];

//...
free (templatesSounds);
```